# Multiple mysql_query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working mysql_query:

```
mysql_query("update products set buyers = buyers+$qtd where id=$pid")  or die (pgs_log("erro linha 70 >".mysql_error()));
```

But then I insert the following query right after it, and it only execute the first one:

```
mysql_query("update products set pending = pending-$qtd where id=$pid")  or die (pgs_log("erro linha 70 >".mysql_error()));
```

So, am I missing something?

Comment: try to `echo` sql queries to the screen and see whether `$qtd` and `$pid` is still working, if it is not, check your `pgs_log` (not sure what does it do). Is the query giving and error or is the page just loading the but database unchanged?

Comment: you have a SQL-injection hole in your code, change `where id=$pid")` into `where id='$id'")`. i.e. enclose all those `$vars` in single quotes or your `mysql_real_escape_string`'s will be for naught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things. First off you don't need two separate queries for this. MySQL may be confused into thinking your value is a column name because of the dash:

```
mysql_query("
UPDATE `products` 
SET `buyers` = `buyers` + $qtd, 
`pending` = `pending` - $qtd 
WHERE `id` = $pid")  or die (pgs_log("erro linha 70 >".mysql_error()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("update `products` 
             set `pending` = `pending` - $qtd, 
                 `buyers` = `buyers` + $qtd 
             where `id` = $pid")  
             or die (pgs_log("erro linha 70 >".mysql_error()));
```

Answer (score 1):

f you wanted to double check that your update actually updated the data then you should investigate [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).  You'll need to check that your old value was different to your new value though, otherwise you'll have zero affected rows, making it a useless check.

You don't use proper quoting around the table and column references.  These should be surrounded with back ticks, and could be combined, like the following:

```
UPDATE
    `products` 
SET
    `pending` = `pending` - $qtd,
    `buyers` = `buyers` + $qtd
WHERE
    `id` = $pid;
```